# Upgrade from .NET3.1 to .NET6.0 is resulting in Jenkins failure

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, aws-lambda

We have a .NET section of our application that utilizes a linux Jenkins box to deploy Lambdas along with an OAuth server.

3.1 going out of support required us to upgrade the codebase to .NET 6.0. The 6.0.412 SDK has been installed onto Jenkins, but everytime we build the application, the 2nd Lambda built fails with the following error:

microsoft.common.currentversion.targets(1220,5): error msb3644: the reference assemblies for .netplatform,version=v6.0 were not found. to resolve this, install the developer pack (sdk/targeting pack) for this framework version or retarget your application...

Running the dotnet --list-sdk on the server itself shows that SDK 6.0.412 is installed.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot what's missing? My impression is that it must be server configs given that error in this context.

**EDIT 1:**

For added context: SDK 6.0.412 is installed on the server.

The first project isn't in .NET 6, it's still in 3.1 so it succeeds. The first instance of .NET 6 Lambdas are what fails.

The current pipeline has Jenkins using the SAM CLI tool to build and publish the .NET code.

Here is the section of the microsoft.common.currentversion.targets that it fails on:

```
<!-- By default if there is no root path set then the task will assume it is Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework-->
<GetReferenceAssemblyPaths
    Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkMoniker)' != '' and ('$(_TargetFrameworkDirectories)' == '' or '$(_FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths)' == '')"
    TargetFrameworkMoniker="$(TargetFrameworkMoniker)"
    RootPath="$(TargetFrameworkRootPath)"
    TargetFrameworkFallbackSearchPaths="$(TargetFrameworkFallbackSearchPaths)"
    BypassFrameworkInstallChecks="$(BypassFrameworkInstallChecks)"
    >
  <Output TaskParameter="ReferenceAssemblyPaths" PropertyName="_TargetFrameworkDirectories"/>
  <Output TaskParameter="FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths" PropertyName="_FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths"/>
  <Output TaskParameter="TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName" PropertyName="TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName" Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName)' == ''"/>
</GetReferenceAssemblyPaths>`
```

This is a linux machine so I'm wondering if it's checking the /Program Files/ path and it just doesn't exist here? Is there a way to explicitly specify this path?

**SOLVED:**

In .NET6.0, the naming syntax of the runtime vs. the framework have diverged. Previously they were both netcoreapp3.1, now the framework is net6.0 and the runtime is dotnet6. We were listing both as dotnet6. Once we changed the framework, the job built fine.

Comment: Is .net installed in your Jenkins agent or server?

Comment: First, Jenkins doesn't care about .NET SDKs. It's written in Java and executes the raw commands specified in the pipeline or by plugins. I use it to build .NET 6, 7 and 8 projects. Second, if the first .NET 6 project works and the second fails, something's wrong with that project, not Jenkins. Try googling the message. The [troubleshooting page for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb3644?view=vs-2022) suggests checking the project file for typos. If you modified the `csproj` manually, it's quite possible there's a typo, eg `net 6.0` instrad of `net6.0`

Comment: For added context: SDK 6.0.412 is installed on the server. The first project isn't in .NET 6, it's still in 3.1 so it succeeds. The first instance of .NET 6 Lambdas are what fails.

If the csproj file had a typo like that, the local build also fails, so I don't think that's a problem here. The Jenkins server calls the SAM CLI to build and this is the response, but it leverages the context of the server and it definitely needs the SDK. I've built these CICD pipelines before, just not with 6.0

Comment: try to publish as self-contained so the .net is not needed on the build server

Comment: That could be an option but my company wouldn't be cool with it as a permanent solution. The standard is for the deployment servers to dynamically grab the code from the repo and do the actual build. That way you don't need to be a dev to run the build commands.